# Display a string in place of a NULL date

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-declarative-helpers

when the date property is set in the model, this is executed:

```
if (!(rdr["JobEnded"] is DBNull)) { job.JobEnded = (DateTime)rdr["JobEnded"]; }
```

which results in job.JobEnded being 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM.

What can I use in place of

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobEnded)
```

to show "In Progress" instead of "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM".

I've tried putting an if/else in the view, but was only able to display a valid date or nothing. I'm sure I'm missing something really basic here as this is my first attempt at an APS.NET MVC view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're dealing with default dates here, so to test for it, you need to use:

```
@if (item.JobEnded == default(DateTime))
{
    @:In Progress
}
else
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.JobEnded)
}
```

Or in one-liner form:

```
@((item.JobEnded == default(DateTime)) ? "In Progress" : Html.DisplayFor(m => item.JobEnded).ToString())
```

Comment: The one-liner causes a compiler complaint: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'string' and 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcHtmlString'

Comment: Edited to add .ToString() - Html.DisplayFor(m => item.JobEnded).ToString()

Comment: Sorry. Yeah, that always bites me without intellisense.